# Code coverage show one line not covered on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage

Code coverage on Visual Studio show one line not covered with my unitary tests even if it enter the function and cover the line before and after. I don't really understand why.

See below (line is said as "Partially covered"):

[image: Code converage]

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Text using comments is preferable to posting _images_ of text.

Comment: Code is not that important right now, I just want to show that all the lines are covered except the one in the middle, that's a nonsense to me.

Comment: Does it behave the same on a Debug build as it does a Release build? Wondering if optimization is eliding code it believes is not necessary?

Comment: I'm doing it in debug build with optimization disabled

Comment: And by doing it in Debug or Release build I have the same behavior.

Comment: Are you able to put a break-point on that line? If not, it's probably eliminated by the compiler.

Comment: I'm able to put a breakpoint with debugger and then step over it.